# Как сделать чтобы текст появлялся около рамки футбольного поля?

Tags: javascript

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var button = document.querySelector('span');


function positionAt(anchor, position, elem){
 var anchorCoords = anchor.getBoundingClientRect();

 if(position == 'left'){
  elem.style.left = anchorCoords.left + 'px';
  elem.style.top = anchorCoords.top - elem.offsetHeight + 'px';
 } else if(position == 'right'){
  elem.style.right = anchorCoords.right + 'px';
  elem.style.top = anchorCoords.top - elem.offsetHeight + 'px';
 }
}
positionAt(div, 'right', button)


var field  = document.querySelector('#field');
var ball  = document.querySelector('#ball');

ball.style.left = Math.round(field.clientWidth / 2 - ball.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
ball.style.top = Math.round(field.clientHeight / 2 - ball.offsetHeight  / 2) + 'px';
```

```css
 #field {
      width: 150px;
      border: 10px groove black;
      background-color: #00FF00;
      position: relative;
      margin: 300px auto;
    }

    #ball {
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="field">
    <img src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" width="40" height="40" id="ball"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
  </div>

<span>какой то текст</span>
```

Comment: в чем вопрос-то? Что должен показывать приведенный код? Как он относится к заголовку?

Comment: @Grundy сделать заметку относительно поля

Comment: @Grundy не получается сделать заметку относительно поля

Comment: @Grundy какой-либо текст можете сами придумать

Comment: что такое заметка? что значит относительно футбольного поля? Что делает предоставленный код?

Comment: @Grundy ничего не делает  код у меня не получилось написать !!! :((((((((((((

Comment: Если код ничего не делает, зачем ты его добавил?

Comment: Где ответы на остальные два вопроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы применялись значения top/left, должен быть установлен `position` отличный от `static`, например `absolute`:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var button = document.querySelector('span');


function positionAt(anchor, position, elem) {
  var anchorCoords = anchor.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (position == 'left') {
    elem.style.left = anchorCoords.left + 'px';
    elem.style.top = anchorCoords.top - elem.offsetHeight + 'px';
  } else if (position == 'right') {
    elem.style.right = anchorCoords.right + 'px';
    elem.style.top = anchorCoords.top - elem.offsetHeight + 'px';
  }
}
positionAt(div, 'left', button)


var field = document.querySelector('#field');
var ball = document.querySelector('#ball');

ball.style.left = Math.round(field.clientWidth / 2 - ball.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
ball.style.top = Math.round(field.clientHeight / 2 - ball.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px';
```

```css
#field {
  width: 150px;
  border: 10px groove black;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  position: relative;
  margin: 300px auto;
}

#ball,
span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <img src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" width="40" height="40" id="ball"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
</div>

<span>какой то текст</span>
```